# Encountering Error in Sqlite3: OperationalError: no such table

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite, dynamic

I am a newbie. I've done some searching but can't seem to find an answer to this issue. I'm trying to run a dynamic data entry with Sqlite3 and Python 3, but I am receiving an error.

It should create a test1.db file, but it's blank.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dominic/Documents/Database_Tutorial.py", line 35, in <module>
dynamic_data_entry()
File "/home/dominic/Documents/Database_Tutorial.py", line 29, in dynamic_data_entry
(unix, date, keyword, value))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: stuffToPlot
```

**Database_Tutorial.py**

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect('test1.db')
c = conn.cursor()


def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffToPlot(unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)")


def data_entry():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES(1452549219,'2016-01-11 13:53:39','Python',6)")

    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()


def dynamic_data_entry():
    unix = int(time.time())
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    keyword = 'Python'
    value = random.randrange(0, 10)

    c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot (unix, datestamp, keyword, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
          (unix, date, keyword, value))

    conn.commit()


for i in range(10):
     dynamic_data_entry()
     time.sleep(1)

c.close
conn.close()
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call create_table() before doing data entry.